# perl loops within subroutines to display the longest repeating string thats selected for a particular subsection of the string

Tags: perl, while-loop, match, subroutine, longest-substring

I was wondering if anyone knows how to simplify, or generalize this code. It gives the correct answer, however it is only applicable to the current situation. My code is as follows:

```
sub longestRepeat{
                                # list of argument @_ is: (sequence, nucleotide)
  my $someSequence = shift(@_);  # shift off the first  argument from the list
  my $whatBP       = shift(@_);  # shift off the second argument from the list
  my $match = 0;



        if ($whatBP eq "AT"){
            if ($someSequence =~ m/(([A][T])\2\2\2\2\2)/g) {

            $match = $1
            }
            return $match;

        }
        if ($whatBP eq "TAGA"){
            if ($someSequence =~ m/(([T][A][G][A])\2\2)/g) {

            $match = $1
            }
            return $match;
        }

        if ($whatBP eq "C"){
            if ($someSequence =~ m/(([C])\2\2)/g) {

            $match = $1
            }
            return $match;
        }
}
```

My question is, in the second if statement, I have it set to a set amount of that pattern being repeated (applicable for the string we were given). However, is there a way to keep doing a while loop to search through the \2 (pattern repeat)? What I mean is can this: if ($someSequence =~ m/(([A][T])\2\2\2\2\2)/g)  be simplified and generalized with a while loop

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of sequences you're looking for the longest repeats of, or are you just looking for the longest repeating sequence of arity 1, 2 and 3?  Also, by longest, do you mean "longest overall" or "most repeats"?  ie. is "CCCC" (4 repeats) longer than "ATATAT" (3 repeats) by your criteria?

Comment: Where I was going with my questions:  You can replace the cascade of `\2` with a simple `+` indicating "one or more", and then accumulate your matches in a histogram, using a pattern like "$histogram{$1}++".  After scanning the entire input sequence, you can then do a second pass on the `keys` of the histogram or histograms to find the "best" match by whatever criteria you're applying.

Comment: @Borys, why did you repost this question when you have already asked it in another post? That's not how things work on this site. You ask a question *one* time only. If you're not receiving the answer that you're looking for then you can edit the question and add more details or clarifications.

Comment: @Zaid Flagged as a duplicate. Borys: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The community here tries very hard to be helpful, In order to avoid wasteful duplication of that effort, it is strongly preferred that a unique question be posted only one time on the site. Moderators enforce this preference by closing duplicates and directing users to the original post containing the question. See the [Stack Overflow Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Comment: @AaronMiller : Voted to close. Although the code posted differs between the two questions, the objective remains the same across both questions: finding the longest repeat sequence. I'll leave it to Borys to edit the other post as he sees fit.

Comment: @Zaid I'm not actually sure he's looked at it since he posted it, to judge by the times. (Do you get a notification when someone answers a question of yours; I wouldn't know; I've only ever asked one question on an SE site, and nobody answered it.)

Comment: @AaronMiller : Yes, you do get notified

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name of your subroutine, I'm assuming that you want to find the longest repeat sequence in your sequence.

If so, how about the following:

```
sub longest_repeat {

    my ( $sequence, $what ) = @_;

    my @matches = $sequence =~ /((?:$what)+)/g ;  # Store all matches

    my $longest;
    foreach my $match ( @matches ) {  # Could also avoid temp variable :
                                      # for my $match ( $sequence =~ /((?:$what)+)/g )

        $longest //= $match ;         # Initialize
                                      #  (could also do `$longest = $match
                                      #                    unless defined $match`)

        $longest = $match if length( $longest ) < length( $match );
    }

    return $longest;  # Note this also handles the case of no matches
}
```

If you can digest that, the following version achieves essentially the same functionality with a Schwartzian transform:

```
sub longest_repeat {

    my ( $sequence, $what ) = @_;                          # Example:
                                                           # --------------------
    my ( $longest ) = map { $_->[0] }                      # 'ATAT' ...
                        sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }       # ['ATAT',4], ['AT',2]
                          map { [ $_, length($_) ] }       # ['AT',2], ['ATAT',4]
                            $sequence =~ /((?:$what)+)/g ; # ... 'AT', 'ATAT'

    return $longest ;
}
```

Some may argue that it is wasteful to `sort` because it is `O(n.log(n))` instead of `O(n)` but there's variety for ya.